# My custom React hook is being called in an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I wrote a custom hook called useApi - I am calling it within Main.tsx. It is being called FROM Main.tsx in an infinite loop. I know this because I put a console.log message right under the line where I implemented it. Also, useApi->go() is being run, but its not remembering any of its own state, which also tells me its being called all over again straight from Main.tsx

Why is this happening?

### What I've noticed so far:

I can terminate this infinite loop by commenting out line 120 of useApi.tsx (setAccessKeyIsValid(true). But this is strange because there is nothing subscribed to this state variable anywhere that would trigger this loop action.  Why is this happening?

Main.tsx:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import useApi from './hooks/useApi';
import Modal from 'react-modal'
import Vim from './Vim';
import './Main.css';
import './modal.css';
Modal.setAppElement('#root')

function Main():JSX.Element { 

  const [postId,updatePostId] = useState<number|null>(null)
  const [content, updateContent] = useState<string>('default text');
  const [auth, updateAuth] = useState<boolean>(false)
  const [authModalIsOpen, setAuthModal] = useState(false)
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')

  const apiUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'

  function openAuthModal(){ setAuthModal(true) }
  function closeAuthModal(){
    if(auth){ setAuthModal(false) }
  }

  const opts = {
    username: 'asdfsdf',
    password: 'asdfsfsfsdfs',
    payload: {
      path: 'notes/',
      method: 'GET',
      body: null,
    },
    complete: (res:{})=>{console.log(res)},
    fail: ()=>{}
  }

  const [options, setOptions] = useState(opts)

  useApi(options)
  console.log('why am I reloading again?')


  function loadPost(pid:number):string|null{
    // fetch from API, load post content
    console.log('I can access:'+postId)
    return null;
  }
  
  
  return (
    <div className='main'>
      <Vim key={postId} content={content} />

      <Modal
        isOpen={authModalIsOpen}
        onRequestClose={closeAuthModal}
        className='Modal'
        overlayClassName='Overlay'
        >
        <form onSubmit={(e)=>{
          e.preventDefault()
          console.log(username)
        }}>
            <input name='username' onChange={(e)=>{
              setUsername(e.target.value)
            }}/>
            <input type="password" name='password' onChange={(e)=>{
              setPassword(e.target.value)
            }}/>
            <button type="submit">Login</button>
          </form>
        </Modal> 
    </div>
  )
}

export default Main
```

useApi.tsx:

```
import {useState, useEffect, useCallback} from 'react'

interface IProps {
    username:string,
    password:string,
    payload:IPayload,
    complete: (result:{})=>void,
    fail: ()=>void
}

interface IPayload {
    path:string,
    method:string,
    body:{}|null,
}

function useApi(props:IProps){

    const [accessKey, setAccessKey] = useState('')
    const [refreshKey, setRefreshKey] = useState('')
    const [refreshKeyIsValid, setRefreshKeyIsValid] = useState<null|boolean>(null)
    const apiUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/'
    const [accessKeyIsValid, setAccessKeyIsValid] = useState<null|boolean>(null)
    const [results, setResults] = useState<null|{}>(null)

    const go = useCallback(()=>{
        const {body, method, path} = props.payload
        console.log('executing GO:'+accessKey)
        const options = {
            method: method,
            headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer '+accessKey,
            },
            ... (body !== null) && { body: JSON.stringify(body) }
        }
        console.log(options)
        fetch(apiUrl+path,options)
        .then(response=>{
            if(response.status===401){
                console.log(response.status)
                setAccessKeyIsValid(false)
            } else {
                response.json()
                .then(response=>{
                    setResults(response)
                })
            }
        })
    },[])


    useEffect(()=>{
        if(results){
            props.complete(results)
        }
    },[results])

    useEffect(()=>{
        if(accessKeyIsValid===false){
            console.log('access key is false')
            // We tried to make a request, but our key is invalid.
            // We need to use the refresh key
            const options = {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', },
                body: JSON.stringify( {'refresh': refreshKey} ),
            }
            fetch(apiUrl+'token/refresh/', options)
            .then(response=>{
                if(response.status === 401 || response.status === 400){
                    setRefreshKeyIsValid(false)
                    // this needs to trigger a login event
                } else {
                    response.json()
                    .then(response=>{
                        setRefreshKeyIsValid(true)
                        setAccessKey(response.access)
                        setAccessKeyIsValid(true)
                    })
                }
            })
        }
    },[accessKeyIsValid])

    useEffect(()=>{
        if(accessKeyIsValid===true){
            // Just refreshed with a new access key. Try our request again
            // go()
        }
    },[accessKeyIsValid, accessKey])

    useEffect(()=>{
        if(refreshKeyIsValid===false){
            console.log('refresh key is now valid')
            // even after trying to login, the RK is invalid
            // We must straight up log in.
            const options = {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    username: props.username,
                    password: props.password,
                 })
            }
            fetch(apiUrl+'token/', options)
            .then(response=>{
                console.log(response.status)
                if(response.status === 401 || response.status ===400){
                    props.fail()
                    console.log('total fail')
                }
                else { 
                    console.log('login works')
                    response.json()
                    .then(response=>{
                        setAccessKey(response.access)
                        setRefreshKey(response.refresh)
                        setRefreshKeyIsValid(true)
                        setAccessKeyIsValid(true) // Commenting this out disables the loop
                    })
                }
            })
        }

        
    },[refreshKeyIsValid])

    return go()
};

export default useApi
```

Comment: If you trigger a state change in a `useEffect` handler of something in the dependency array you will get an infinite loop. Every time.

Comment: maybe `return go()` activate go function

Comment: First thing that catches my eye, and I doubt it's the problem, but doesn't `go` need `accessKey` in its dependencies?  Otherwise the closure is stuck with the initial value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what's going on is a combination of all three comments:

1. effects that update their own dependencies.
2. executing `go()` rather than returning it.
3. creating `go` as a closure that never updates its `accessToken`.

You're executing `go` on every state change, but executing it with an empty `accessKey` because the `useCallback` does not have `accessToken` in its dependency array.  You get an invalid response, so you set `accessKeyIsValid` to `false`.  This triggers your other effects and eventually you get to the line that you commented out, where you set `accessKeyIsValid` to `true`.  But that state change triggers a re-render so `go()` runs again and sets it back to `false`, continuing the loop.